# Postfix forwarding mail with virtual mailboxes present

Tags: configuration, postfix, redmine, cyrus

I have mail server setup to use postfix and cyrus imapd + ldap for mail lookups.

Now I would like to specify that for particular address (e.g. *someuser@domain.com*) instead of delivering mail to mailbox it gets passed to script (ruby script to be more precise). I need this functionality since I would like to have mails passed to particular address to end up on our redmine server. How to do this?

Currently I have in *main.cf*:

```
...
mydestination = $mydomain, mail.$mydomain
local_recipient_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapvirtual.cf
local_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp
...
```

*/etc/postfix/ldapvirtual.cf* is LDAP configuration file to search for mail addresses.

What do I need to configure on postfix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `master.cf` you create a new "ruby" configuration for the ruby script to accept mails. This is done via `pipe` as described in http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html
You can probably already see some examples (with `pipe` in the last column) in your current `master.cf`. But how to configure it depends on the ruby script and the related system environment.

Then you need a file (for example) `/etc/postfix/transport_maps` with the content

```
someuser@example.com    ruby:
other@example.net    ruby:
```

This will pass mails for these persons to the ruby transport you configured in `master.cf` as long as you named it "ruby". Then run `postmap /etc/postfix/transport_maps`.

After that you need a new line in `main.cf` with

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport_maps
```

Reload the Postfix daemon. From then the configured addresses go through ruby and the others go through the transport configured with `local_transport`.

Comment: I did as suggested, but mails to above example someuser@example.com is being rejected with error 550 Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table ##. I guess that I need to add above address to some other maps, but I don't know to which map and to what it should point to?

Comment: This is absolutely unrelated to this question. This has to be fixed before asking this question. The address must be in your LDAP (and the domain, too).

Comment: If I add address to LDAP, it will automatically deliver to user account (since cyrus will create non existant account on delivery attempt). How does postfix decides to deliver to particular transport? If seems to me that postfix is ignoring transport_maps in my setup (postconf does show it is configured).

Comment: Postfix decides on the transport map as described in http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html

Comment: You were right. After I cleaned a lot of other configuration that were causing problems, **it worked**!